# Pyramid POST /login HTTP1.1 404 error

Tags: python, web, pyramid, pylons

I am new to Python, Pyramid and Web. I am trying to write a simple app with main page and login page. For that I have two files: `login.pt` and `main.pt`.

When I go to 0.0.0.0:8080 I get login page. Now, if I enter the correct data (login and password) I will get to the main page, but in the console of my IDE I get this string:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2015 14:52:59] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 404 158
```

In my views.py I have a `login` method, which checks login and pass.

How to fix it?

update

in application.py:

```
def main():
    config = Configurator()
    config.scan("views")
    config.add_static_view(name="i", path="i")
    config.add_route('login', '/login')
    config.add_route('main_page', '/main')
    app = config.make_wsgi_app()
    return app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = main()
    server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 8080, app)
    server.serve_forever()
```

in views.py:

```
@view_config(route_name = 'login', renderer="login1.pt")
def login(request):
    checking


@view_config(route_name = 'main_page', renderer = 'main.pt')
def main_view(request):
    return{}
```

Comment: please show source code of your view_config calls and routes initialization.

Comment: @view_config(renderer="login1.pt")
def login(request):
checking for data 

@view_config(route_name = 'main_page', renderer = 'main.pt')
def main_view(request):
    return{}

def main():
    config = Configurator()
    config.scan("views")
    config.add_route('main_page', '/main')
    app = config.make_wsgi_app()
    return app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = main()
    server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 8080, app)
    server.serve_forever()

why it writes in one string with no enters?

Comment: You did not add route for your login view

Comment: how i should add it?

Comment: So, instead @view_config(renderer="login1.pt") do @view_config(route_name='login', renderer="login1.pt") and add call config.add_route('login', '/login') in the main function.

Comment: so i got this 
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2015 15:39:14] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 2011

127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2015 15:39:24] "POST /loginlogin HTTP/1.1" 404 163

127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2015 15:39:24] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 2011

Comment: put all the source code formatted to the question please

Comment: Source code looks OK.  POST /loginlogin - why this happened? Check your form HTML code.

Comment: maybe some problems with architecture in my app? how must it looks like?
maybe i should have 2 views and additional method to check login and pass?

Comment: tell me what's in your action attribute of form tag on login page.

Comment: <p><input type="password" name="password" id="password" maxlength="50" 
      onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('login_button').click()"
      placeholder="Пароль"/>

You mean this? @DmitryNedbaylo

Comment: not really, i wanted to see form, not only input. i suggest you add your code to github or gist.

Comment: @DmitryNedbaylo   http://pastebin.ru/bODiYwIw

Comment: where do you send POST request in your JS?

Comment: @DmitryNedbaylo this method in my file.js   http://pastebin.ru/HPIur4qa

Answer (score 0):

Base on the comments above, you [html code](http://pastebin.ru/bODiYwIw) and `file.js (Page not found`

```
<input type="button" value="Вход" id="login_button" onclick="javascript:login();"/>
```

I think you are using ajax POST?
Try add a new function like this

```
@view_config(route_name = 'login', xhr=True, renderer='json')
def login_ajax(request):
    checking
```

Comment: It didn`t help. In fact my problem that my application cannot find some function in my file.js and i do not know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

I just removed javascript from my project. Instead i use request.route_path()